# Reading each char in a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Is it possible to identify the location and presence of a specific char in a NSString within the objective-c framework? For example, if I have the NSString @"hello" and I wanted to know the location and presence of the char "e", how would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is particular method for searching for single characters within a string, but you can just search for the range of a substring of length 1 and request the returned range's location, as such:

```
NSRange charRange = [@"hello" rangeOfString:@"e"];
NSUInteger index = charRange.location;
if (index == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"substring not found");
}
```

You can find full documentation here: [`rangeOfString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3a)

To find the indices of all `@"e"` in `@"hello"` you might want to do something like this, though:

```
NSString *haystack = @"hellol";
NSString *needle = @"l";
NSMutableIndexSet *indices = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
NSUInteger haystackLength = [haystack length];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, haystackLength);
NSRange searchRange = range;
while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    range = [haystack rangeOfString:needle options:0 range:searchRange];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        [indices addIndex:range.location];
        NSUInteger searchLocation = range.location + 1;
        NSUInteger searchLength = haystackLength - searchLocation;
        if (searchLocation >= haystackLength) {
            break;
        }
        searchRange = NSMakeRange(searchLocation, searchLength);
    }
}
//indices now holds the indices of all occurrences of 'e' in "hello".
```

Documentation: [NSMutableIndexSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableIndexSet/addIndex%3a), [NSIndexSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSIndexSet)

**Edit:** Replaced algorithm with the one from **@bbum**'s as described in his comment to this answer.

Comment: ... and you'll get a location of 'NSNotFound' if there's no 'e'.

Comment: Yeah, was just adding that to my answer while you commented. ;)

Comment: What would return to `index` if I instead messaged: `[@"hello" rangeOfString:@"l"]`?

Comment: Well, `index` would be `2` (first occurrence of match).

Comment: is there a way to know both positions of both "l"s?

Comment: Or use `rangeOfString:options:range:` and pass a range beyond the first occurrence.  Accumulate the results until you hit `NSNotFound`.

Comment: @bbum, I'm curious as to whether you'd advise this even for single-char needles in potentially huge strings?

Comment: In a potentially huge string, you are going to need to chunk the lookups anyway as you don't want to copy a huge amount of data (a 512K string would blow out the stack of a non-main thread w/that code, for example).   I'd probably go w/the `rangeOfString:...` pattern because it is both easy to optimize and scalable as is (not that your code is wrong).

Comment: @cfarm54 see my just edited answer for a sample of how **bbum**'s suggested algorithm c/would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Apple Docs for [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString
```